# In an attribute's format (and using Color as an example), what is the difference between 'color' and 'color|reference'?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-attributes

### TLDR version

I get why `reference` is used as the format for attributes which point to default styles when setting up default theming, but how does using `reference|color` differ from just using `color` when defining color attributes? You can already use `@color/xxx` which is already a reference to another resource so is reference implicit?  If not, what's the use-case for one over the other?

### Full version

I've been following best-practices for theming our application's custom widgets using the following recommended technique.

### In attrs.xml

```
<!-- Attributes holding default styles -->
<attr name="myWidgetStyle"      format="reference" />
<attr name="myOtherWidgetStyle" format="reference" />

<!-- Custom attributes -->
<attr name="indicatorColor" format="color|reference" />

<!-- Assigning attributes to controls -->
<declare-styleable name="MyWidget">
    <item name="android:text" />
    <item name="indicatorColor" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="MyOtherWidget">
    <item name="android:text" />
    <item name="indicatorColor" />
</declare-styleable>
```

### In styles.xml

```
<style name="ThemeBase">

    <!-- Store default style in the style-reference attributes -->
    <item name="myWidgetStyle">@style/MyWidget</item>
    <item name="myOtherWidgetStyle">@style/MyOtherWidget</item>

    <!-- Reference primaryColor attribute when defining the value for this one -->
    <item name="indicatorColor">?primaryColor</item>
    <!-- alternate: <item name="indicatorColor">?attr/primaryColor</item> -->

</style>

<style name="ThemeA" parent="ThemeBase">
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor_themeA</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeB" parent="ThemeBase">
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor_themeB</item>
</style>
```

Then finally, in the constructors for my widgets, I pass `R.attr.myWidgetStyle` and `R.attr.myOtherWidgetStyle` as appropriate to both the call to `super` as well as to `context.obtainStyledAttributes` and I can get the defined colors as need.  Everything works as expected. My controls are themed appropriately.

However, what I'm wondering is I've sometimes seen this in the attrs.xml file...

```
<attr name="indicatorColor" format="color" /> <-- Note no 'reference'
```

and everything still works, leaving me scratching my head on why you would write `color|reference` instead of just `color`.  I've tried cascading changes through several attributes, defining them in different orders and anything else I could think of to get different results, but they all just work.

So does anyone have an explanation?

***Even better, can someone post an example showing different behavior between `color` and `color|reference` because as of now, I have yet to find one.***

Comment: see `<attr name="background" format="reference|color" />` in attrs.xml - it is commented as: *<!-- A drawable to use as the background.  This can be either a reference
             to a full drawable resource (such as a PNG image, 9-patch,
             XML state list description, etc), or a solid color such as "#ff000000"
            (black). -->*

Comment: Aaaah... so "color|reference" isn't saying it can take a color or a color reference, it's saying it can take a color (direct/attribute/resource) *or* a *non-color* reference!  In other words, if our particular attribute will always take only colors, we don't need, nor should put the 'reference' portion, correct?

Comment: i made some checks and it seems the `format` is really broken, see [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486028/in-an-attributes-format-and-using-color-as-an-example-what-is-the-difference#comment78018810_45486391)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute format is only for the system to know what type of resource this attribute can be.

color = any color. Hex (#ffffffff) or link to color resource (@color/supa-awesome_color). No @drawable/mega_icon are allowed here

reference = any reference (@color/supa_awesome_color, @drawable/mega_icon, @string/hi_there, ...)

color|reference = is an union of the above

Comment: What about '?attr/someColorAttr' as the value?  Isn't that saying 'Use this attribute's value as the value for that attribute too?' (i.e. a reference?)  And if that is a reference, how come removing 'reference' from the format doesn't seem to make any difference? Is reference implied for colors?

Comment: Can you give a code example showing a difference in behavior between 'color' and 'color|reference'?  Again, I'm not seeing any difference in behavior or what I'm allowed to store there.

Comment: Lint not checking reference in color. But the difference is, that AndroidStudio will suggest you only colors in 'color' and colors and references in 'color|reference'

Comment: But isn't specifying a color resource a reference?  And if not, what exactly *is* a color reference then?

Comment: You can specify color as reference to color res and as color-hex directly. The second is not a reference

Comment: Yes, but if an attribute is specified as just a 'color' and not a 'color|reference', it can still take @color references, which begs my question... then what's the difference between the two?  That's why I'm asking for a code sample to demonstrate where there's a difference of behavior.  I'm starting to think there isn't one because again, the 'color'-only version seems to take references just fine.

Comment: Even in your example above you show the color-only version taking @color references which is why I'm asking the question "what's the difference between 'color' and 'color|reference'".  I hope that's finally clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Put one last way, what can 'color|reference' accept that 'color' by itself cannot, or vice-versa?

Comment: Color only version should take reference to only color res, but 'reference' can take any reference. So, 'color' shouldn't accept any reference and Android Studio suggests you only color references for 'color' attributes.

Comment: `"No @drawable/mega_icon are allowed here"` not really, the `format` in styles/styleables is broken: i made some additional checks and if you have `format=color` you can still pass `@drawable/mega_icon`, it seems that some checks against the format are made but i couldnt find any simple rule

Comment: Maybe they're just hints for Lint, etc., and not something that's actually enforced by the compiler/runtime.